# how to replace url in webview android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

i am getting first that URL contain ad then i want to replace ad with as how to replace ad with as.

```
  @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Uri data = intent.getData();
      //want to check contains in data and if contains i want to replace it
    if(data.toString().contains("ad")){
        data.toString() = data.toString().replace("ad", "xyz");
    }

    try {

        webView.loadUrl(data.toString());
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: anybody can help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method that may help you is below which you should put into the @override method

```
String myUrl = url;
myUrl = myUrl.replace("ad", as);
```

**Then** use the new string wherever you want .
**You can't change the original url :)**

The Method replace returns the string value as API DOC says

```
public String replace (CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)
```

Try to do this :

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
super.onStart();
Intent intent = getIntent();
Uri data = intent.getData();
String mString;
  //want to check contains in data and if contains i want to replace it
if(data.toString().contains("ad")){
    mString = data.toString().replace("ad", "xyz");
}

try {

    webView.loadUrl(mString);
}
catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: why are you asigning data.toString() to the other values do not do this try to asign to a variable like in the answer and one more thing is that try to put your errors that is coming in logcat with the qyestion you ask.