# How do I check that Uri data contains some words and then replace it in webview?

Tags: android, webview

I first check that the Uri data contains ad, and then I want to replace ad with as how to replace ad with as.

```
  @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Uri data = intent.getData();

 //want to check contains in data and if contains i want to replace it

        if(data.contains("ad")){
            data.replace("ad", "as");
        }
        try {
            webView.loadUrl(data.toString());
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: data=data.replace("ad", "as");

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to replace url in webview android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61409306/how-to-replace-url-in-webview-android-studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uri does not have `contains` and `replace`, so you have to convert to `String` first.

Try this:

```
if (data != null) {
    String uriString = data.toString();
    if (uriString.contains("ad")) {
        uriString = uriString.replace("ad", "as");
    }
    try {
       webView.loadUrl(uriString);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```